# As soon as I am putting debugger in my project ,i am getting the error PDB file not loaded while debugging

Tags: asp.net

When I am trying to debug my asp.net application,which is a three layered architecture.It doesn't hit the break point and displays the message that .pdb file not loaded.I am aware that this will not affect in loading of application.But it doesn't allow me to debug my code,and being a developer it is a must requirement.
Please help me.

Comment: You have to use Debug configuration.

Comment: How is your solution set up? Are all layers in the same solution? If not, are the .PDB files next to the .DLL files? Did you try searching for "pdb file not loaded"?

Comment: @MateuszRadny Please tell me how to use debug configuration??

Comment: All three layers are in the same solution.The .pdb files get generated in my bin.I did find them in my bin,but still tell me anywhere else i should search it for??i am new to VS.I am using VS 2012

Answer (score 0):

I actually asked this question.
But i didn't find any answers working for me.
But later i resolved the issue myself.What i did was i took the complete folder where my code was stored and put it at a separate location and then connected my Visual Studio yet again with TFS and everything worked fine.